# ssh works after reboot, but then stops

Tags: 18.04, ssh

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 on a desktop in my office. From home, I can ssh into it.
However, I find that if I reboot the desktop remotely, initially ssh still works fine. But after I log out and some period of time passes, ssh times out, and the only solution is for me to physically log in, then ssh works again.

Any ideas as to what I can change to avoid this issue?

thanks!

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u sshd`.

Comment: That log is empty...